# Heston model characteristic function

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston, call, characteristic-function

The characteristic function of $x=ln(S_T)$ in the framework of Heston model is guessed to be: $$f_j(\phi,x,v)=e^{C_j(\tau,\phi)+D_j(\tau,\phi)+i\phi x}$$

The call price is guessed to have the form: $$C_T(K)=e^{x_t}P_1(x,v,\tau)-e^{r \tau}KP_2(x,v,\tau)$$

where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are probabilities that an option expires in-the-money w.r.t proper measures.

Now, I can follow the derivation of the PDE for $P_1$ and $P_2$ $$\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial \tau}+\rho \sigma v\frac{\partial^2 P_j}{\partial x \partial v}+\frac{1}{2}v\frac{\partial^2 P_j}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{2}v\sigma \frac{\partial^2 P_j}{\partial v^2}+(r+u_jv)\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial x}+(a-b_jv)\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial v}=0$$
where $j=1,2$, $u_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $u_2=-\frac{1}{2}$, $a=\kappa \theta$, $b_1=\kappa + \lambda -\rho \sigma$, $b_2 = \kappa + \lambda$ and $\tau = T - t$.

However, I cannot understand and couldn't find any resources online which would justify why characteristic functions $f_j(\phi,x,v)$ also have to satisfy the very same PDE. Most of them just say it's the result of Feynman-Kac formula, but I cannot understand the link. Could someone explain it or point me to an appropriate source (article, textbook, whatever), please?

Comment: The PDE's are satisfied for any twice-differentiable function $f$, which is the conditional expectation of a function of $v$ and $x$, i.e. $f(x,v,t) = \mathbb{E}\left[g(X_T,V_T) \vert X_t = x, V_t =v\right]$. The proof is in the appendix of Heston's original [paper](https://www.frouah.com/finance%20notes/The%20Heston%20model%20short%20version.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, from that perspective I understand.

Comment: @Achrbot I followed the appendix but don't quite get (A7) could you please elaborate? First the original paper says, guess $f(x,v,t)=\exp \left[C(T-t)+D(T-t)v+i\phi x\right]$ (A6) then submit into (A2) -- I suppose this is a typo, it shall be (A4). Then it got 2 equations in (A7), but I don't get it. For example, where was $-\frac12 \sigma^2 \phi^2$ from? I get $f_{xx} = -\phi^2 f$, then $\frac12 v f_{xx}$ from (A4) shall become $-\frac12 v \phi^2$, not $-\frac12 \sigma^2\phi^2$.

Comment: I think this is a typo in the original article. See for example page 11 in [The Heston model and its extensions in Matlab and C#](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Multi-Language/The%20Heston%20Model%20and%20Its%20Extensions%20in%20MATLAB%20and%20C%23%20%5BRouah%202013-09-03%5D.pdf).

Comment: @Achrbot thanks for recommending, it's a good book!